# Github api error redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: api, github, oauth, uri

I keep getting this same OAuth error when trying to work with the github api. Sometimes it goes away but most of the time it stays. I have tried resetting my secret key, revoking all tokens, clearing safari cache but no luck. This is the error : `error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=The+redirect_uri+MUST+match+the+registered+callback+URL+for+this+application.&error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.github.com%2Fv3%2Foauth%2F%23redirect-uri-mismatch`

All the forums say to fix this error, remove the redirect_uri parameter of my request which I have done.

This is my request: `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=myclientid&scope=user,public_repo`

Everything shows up and when I click authorize it redirects me back to my application but instead of giving me the code it gives me the error.[image]

Comment: You sorted that out?

Comment: The only time I was able to reproduce this was when I specified a `redirect_uri` that didn't match, which shouldn't matter since you say you removed it.  Do you have an Authorization callback URL that you could post?  

Do you also get that message if you exclude the browser - say using cURL or Postman?

Comment: Issue fixed. It was an issue with capital letters in m application. Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

Either put `http` instead of `https` in your **Authorization callback URL**

in your GitHub OAuth apps settings.

```
http://www.example.com/oauth/complete/github/
```

> Another Option

**settings.py**

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_REDIRECT_IS_HTTPS = True
```